# mod_rewrite log analyzer / Automatic tool for analyzing htaccess log files for problems / speed issues

Tags: .htaccess, logging, url-rewriting, performance

The url rewritten pages on my site load up extremely slow and I'm looking for a software that can analyze the logs to help point out where the problem is.

I have set RewriteLogLevel to be 2 (but can set it whatever is appropriate). I am looking for a program / website service that can analyze that log and/or my .htaccess file and tell me what's taking the most time / where the problem lies.

Comment: Mmm... A more exact way of describing what you are looking for would be a *mod_rewrite profiler*. Don't know whether such a thing exists - interesting question

Comment: Hi @Pekka  - interesting... i wasnt aware of that term. but i wasnt able to find anything on the net on that as well...

Comment: @matt it's probably more fitting, because the rewrite rules have nothing to do with .htaccess. But I can't see anything under that name either

Comment: @Pekka - I'm confused by your statement - htaccess contains the rewrite statements...

Comment: @matt no, they could as well reside in the central configuration. It doesn't make a difference where they are

Comment: @matt74tm It seems unlikely that mod_rewrite is the culprit here, at least directly. However, I guess anything's possible. I doubt a profiler exists for this purpose (although I am working on something to identify problem areas in rewrite rule sets), but if you'd like to post either your rules or your log here it's possible we could help you figure out what's going awry.

Comment: @Pekka Well, it makes a *bit* of a difference, but the point of calling mod_rewrite by its proper name still stands, yeah. ;)

Comment: Hi @Tim - there's no problem with mod_rewrite itself, just the rules that we're using that is causing the browser experience to be slow overall. We have a LOT of them and they may not be setup efficiently (as some have already pointed out at). Please see the rules here at: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4237/url-rewritten-pages-take-much-longer-to-load

Comment: @Tim - I would be very interested in knowing more about "something to identify problem areas in rewrite rule sets"!

Comment: @Tim Stone - just wondering if I can get to know more about your solution for identifying problem areas in rewrite rules...

Comment: @matt74tm It's just a side project of mine, but it's not done enough to put up on the web for people to use yet. As for your current rules, I've been meaning to take a more in depth look at them, but I've been busy with work the last week or so; sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

1. if you have the choice avoid using .htaccess, Apache will have to check each directory along the path for the existence of .htaccess.
2. A .htaccess file is read each time a URI request is made.
3. A .htaccess file is parsed from top to bottom and if it's long it will take time to process
4. The regex that you might be using for writing URLs might have impact on the performances. There are techniques for improving regex. For example, you can check this article about [performances on Java regex](http://www.javaworld.com/cgi-bin/mailto/x_java.cgi?pagetosend=/export/home/httpd/javaworld/javaworld/jw-09-2007/jw-09-optimizingregex.html&pagename=/javaworld/jw-09-2007/jw-09-optimizingregex.html&pageurl=http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2007/jw-09-optimizingregex.html&site=jw_core).

In general it is better to put everything in httpd.conf, because all the rules are created at the start of apache instance and live in the memory not on the disk like .htaccess with filesystem access.

Comment: totally with you! I'm having a huge slowdown because of htaccess / mod_rewrite rules, but I can't decipher where the problem is...!